# Is "dawdle" a common verb in American English?

Tags: verbs, american-english

Is "dawdle" a common verb in American English? In my limited experience I have never heard Americans use it.

Comment: Australians use it quite often.

Comment: I use it every day.  (Er, I mean I dawdle every day -- I'm doing it right now, in fact.)  (It's definitely well-known and used with reasonable frequency in the US.  Just not the type of word that would come up in formal language, in the news, etc.  But well known to parents.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking on the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* for *dawdle*, and comparing the result with what reported by the *British National Corpus*, I would say that the word is not so common in American English, but it is used more in American English than in British English.

[image: search results]

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I don't quite understand what it means "not so common, but is used more" - to me it sounds self-contradictory. Can you, please, explain.

Comment: @brillant It is not self-contradictory. A word that is used in 59 sentence in fiction contexts, and it is used 29 times in newspapers, it is not what I would call a common word. The same word, however, is less frequently used in British English; that means it is more common in American English than in British English. I don't see any contradiction.

Comment: I'm surprised by these results.  "Dawdle" is an informal word.  Seeing so few spoken instances relative to the newspaper and magazine columns seems odd.

Comment: @Rhodri You should then be surprised to see the word used in academic context, even if in that case there are just six sentences.

Comment: Actually, neither the NOAD nor the OED reports _dawdle_ is informal.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: reported or not, it's not a word I expect to see written often.  I'm rarely surprised by anything academics do any more, living in a university town!

Comment: I check informal/formal, by prepending 'Your majesty,...' to the sentence and seeing if it sounds weird.

Comment: I usually add "you sick thing" at the beginning of the sentence, and check if the sentence is nicer. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

From an AmE speaker, this is perfectly fine. It's not a particularly common or newspaper-y word. It is most commonly used (and often) in the context:

> Quit dawdling and tie you shoes or you'll be late for school.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost never used in formal situations. It's the kind of language you'd use when talking to a family member or a friend, but not when talking to a professor or a coworker. I'd say it's common enough that even people who don't use it themselves will know what it means if someone says it to them.

Comment: I disagree. If anything, I am *more* likely to use it, or similar terms like *dilly-dally*, in formal communication in lieu of phrases like *spinning her wheels* or *sitting on his ass*.

Comment: Maybe use of the phrase differs regionally? I've rarely heard it used outside of the context of an adult talking to a child, as in "Come straight home after school, and don't dawdle." In a more formal or professional setting, words like _procrastinate_ or _put off_ seem more common.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard it used, but with such a common meaning ("spend more time than is necessary going somewhere. *Eleanor will be back any moment, if she doesn't dawdle*") I cannot see any reason why I wouldn't be used in the right context.